# Implement interface property that is an interface

Tags: c#

Given the code below I get the following errors, that the parent and child don't implement IParent/IChild. I have clearly misunderstood something. What is the correct way to implement this or am I better off using abstract classes?

To add more detail, these classes are used in EF so I need to implement rather than having an abstract type. "The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter."

```
public interface IParent
{
    int ParentId { get; set; }
    IChild Child { get; set; }
}

public interface IChild
{
    int ChildId { get; set; }
    IParent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent : IParent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried an explicit implementation of the interface?

```
public class Parent : IParent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
    public int IParent.ParentId { get { return ParentId; } set { ParentId = value; } }
    public IChild IParent.Child { get { return Child; } set { Child = value; } }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public int IChild.ChildId { get { return ChildId; } set { ChildId = value } } }
    public IParent IChild.Parent { get { return Parent; } set { Parent = value } } }
}
```

Note: I've not actually tried to compile this, there may be some ambiguity in the getter and setter of the explicit implementation so you may have to get and set backing fields instead of the properties.

Comment: To add more detail, these classes are used in EF so I need to implement rather than having an abstract type.  The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter.

Comment: What's the purpose of the interfaces then? You could do away with them and simplify your model. Another option might be to implement them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Your IParent and IChild define the properties as IChild and IParent, not Child and Parent, even though you can assign those to the properties. Therefore, the original code:

```
public class Parent : IParent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Should become:

```
public class Parent : IParent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public IChild Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public IParent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant change the signature of the interface, you can do something like this

```
public class Parent : IParent
{
    private Child _child;
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public IChild Child
    {
        get { return _child; }
        set { _child = (Child)value; } //dangerous zone
    }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    private Parent _parent;
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public IParent Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
        set { _parent = (Parent)value; } //dangerous zone
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says your classes need to implement the interfaces, so you classes need to be defined as below:

```
public class Parent : IParent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public IChild Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public IParent Parent { get; set; }
}
```